# Never Have Access to Embedded SWF Content Through Loader

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I am working on embedding a SWF that is just a converted PDF created with InDesign. The SWF is 15 pages, 1 page per frame. It *does* include TLF text and there is no way around that unless the document is completely recreated in Flash. The problem is that when I load the SWF into my application, I never have access to the root MovieClip.

```
this.loader = new Loader();
this.loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.INIT, this.loaderInitHandler );
this.loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, this.loaderInitHandler );
this.loader.load( new URLRequest( "assets/doc.swf" ) );
```

When I look at the loader after both the INIT and COMPLETE events as well as later on by stopping the app in debug mode, I do not see a MovieClip. Instead, the `loader.content` is of type `doc_fla.MainTimeline__Preloader__` which contains two children, an empty `Shape` and another `Loader`. That loader, when checking INIT and COMPLETE events results in the exact same situation and it appears to be a never ending line of Loaders whose contents are "Preloaders".

Could anyone shed some light as to what is causing this or how I might fix it? I've poured a good 2 hours into solving this and I am no closer to a solution than when I started.

- ActionScript Mobile project
- Compiling using AIR 3.6
- Testing in emulator as well as on iPad and on Nexus 7

Comment: Are you loading a two-component SWF starting with a preloader instead of loading only the main part of that SWF?

Comment: Uh... I have no idea. I published from CS6 and I am loading it using a standard Loader. I'm using the exact same method for two others SWFs in this project and they work just fine. The only differences I can think of are that this SWF has multiple frames and it has TLF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recompiled the SWF and embedded the TLF libraries (under ActionScript settings, just set the TLF swc which was already there to be embedded) in it and this seems to have fixed the issue. I swear I had tried that before to no success, but it worked this time.